# Fedora just warned me hard drive might fail soon

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, hard-drive-failure

So I bought a "Asus X540LA Laptop, Intel Core i7-5500U 2.4GHz, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD" in June this year. And today I got a warning that the HDD would fail in <24 hours. I ran smartctl to diagnose the issue and got the following output (on pastebin because it's quite large) https://pastebin.com/xrQp4hpv

Is this a legitimate issue? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What gave you the warning, and any indication (or in it's docs) why?

Comment: GNOME notification popped up saying it would fail soon

Comment: Probably some smartctl daemon monitor always checking I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first make a backup (it's always a good decision) just to sleep better at night.

That being said, from what I can tell by reading the output those 3 errors are quite old:

```
Error 2 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1295 hours (53 days + 23 hours)
```

It's possible that you had a power failure 53 days + 23 hours ago (check the messages log) which caused those errors to be logged and the disk has no actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

You got the warning due to a high `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME         FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   062   062   062    NOW  572391424
```

You also have 3 logged crc errors with the sector number given (`ABRT at LBA = 0x6e44b467 = 1849996391`), but perhaps they all occurred at the same time due to mechanical or electrical disturbance, and may not be associated with the failure.

The read error rate however suggests that many blocks are having to be read several times by this drive until it gets a good crc that means the data was read ok.

What you can do is run a short or long non-destructive selftest that will try to read each cylinder or sector and provide statistics on how successful it was. Do `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` or `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` and it will say something like `Please wait 180 seconds for test to complete.` After this time, redo the `smartctl -a` to see the result and any new information it provides.

Comment: So that's what the self-tests do, just read data? I'm guessing the short one only picks a few random spots, while long is... longer

Comment: The short test changed everything to pre-fail or old-age and reading the documentation now looks like everything's fine. Putting it down to a blip